# Javascript calculator in JSF view calling server side

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to make a calculator in a jsf view using only client-side part. No data can be passed to server-side.

I have the view splitted in a couple of `<h:form>` with calculator in the middle:

```
<h:form id="customer_form">
// view here working nice
</h:form>                   

<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="ui-grid-col-2 offset-boxes" >

    <p:panel id="calculator" header="Calculadora" styleClass="half-screen-height calculator-table">

        <h:inputText id="result" widgetVar="result" styleClass="result-text"/>
        <p:button value="X" widgetVar="X" ajax="false" onclick="calculate('x')" styleClass="right"></p:button>

        // more calculator buttons   

    </p:panel>

</h:panelGroup>

<h:form id="consumption_form">
// view here working nice
</h:form>
```

Until here all is ok, but when I try to manage calculator with `javascript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(sel){
        if (sel == "x") {
            document.getElementById("result").value = "";
        } else {
            var input = document.getElementById("result").value;
            document.getElementById("result").setAttribute("value", input + sel);
        }                   
    }
</script>
```

Each time i change `result` value, server-side is called and value is reset to original `value`.

***EDIT*** according to PrimeFaces documentation of `p:button::onclick` event

> Client side callback to execute when button is clicked.

Either `<h:button>` tag is acting like this, so I guess problem is the way `JSF` or `PrimeFaces` are handling the javascript event...

*I also tried to call and set input value by `jquery` with `$("result").value` but the result i get is a `function(b7)` not the value itself.*

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks! ;)

J

Comment: If you don't want to send anything to the server side why not use plain Javascript to do the job? It will be easier and less mixed code to handle, you can easily use a JS component as well.

Comment: something like?, i tried several things and nothing seems to work... :(

Comment: there are several JS examples out there like : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631525/Creating-Calculator-using-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript

Comment: of course i've tried several things like that. I can easy make a javascript calculator in an html page, but here I think `jsf` is doing it's "*magic*" in the background and calling server side in a way i cant figure out.

Comment: you got to make sure you're JS code will not try to submit the  form, so that will trigger a server side call, for that I suggest you return false and try using event.preventDefault() on your buttons, so you will avoid bubbling up the event to any listeners.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` at the end of the `function` was exactly what I needed dude! Post it as answer so I can vote you! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got to make sure you're JS code will not try to submit the form, so that will trigger a server side call, for that I suggest you return false and try using event.preventDefault() on your HTML buttons onclick calls, so you will avoid bubbling up the event to any listeners.